# Typescript: Add dynamic property with type safety

Tags: typescript, types

I have a function that adds the property `imageUrl` to an object based on a `fileProperty` param:

```
public async appendImageUrl<T>(
    value: T,
    fileProperty: keyof T,
): Promise<{ imageUrl: string } & T> {
    const imageUrl = ...
    return {
        ...value,
        imageUrl,
    };
}
```

Example: `appendImageUrl({a: '...', imageId: '...'})` will return `{a: '...', imageId: '...', imageUrl: '...'}`.

Now my question: I want to provide the name of the "target property" (until now `imageUrl`) dynamically. I tried the following:

```
public async appendPresignedUrl<T, K extends keyof R, R extends T & Record<K, string>>(
    value: T,
    fileProperty: keyof T,
    targetProperty: K,
): Promise<R> {
    const presignedUrl = ...
   
    return {
        ...value,
        [targetProperty]: presignedUrl,
    };
}
```

This gives me the following error:

> Type 'T & { [x: string]: string; }' is not assignable to type 'R'.
> 'R' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'T & { [x: string]: string; }'.ts(2322)

I do understand the problem but couldn't find solution yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is mostly a known limitation or bug in TypeScript; see [microsoft/TypeScript#13948](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13948). If you use a [computed property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names) in an object literal and that property name isn't known to the compiler to be a single string [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types), then the type of the key is widened all the way to `string` and you get a [string index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures). Until and unless that's fixed you could work around it with a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions), or if you're going to do that a lot, wrap the type assertion in a helper function like this:

```
function kv<K extends PropertyKey, V>(key: K, value: V) {
  return { [key]: value } as { [P in K]: { [Q in P]: V } }[K];
}
```

The `kv()` function takes a key of type `K` and a value of type `V` and returns an object whose type has a property with that key type and that value type.  There are all kinds of caveats with this sort of object creation.  The "obvious" return type would be [`Record<K, V>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype) (equivalent to `{[P in K]: V}`), but if `K` is a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) then that results in the wrong output.  If you call `kv(Math.random()<0.5?"a":"b", 123)` you want something like `{a: number} | {b: number}` and not `{a: number; b: number}`, right?  If so, then we need the more complicated `{ [P in K]: { [Q in P]: V } }[K]` type.  Let's just test it quickly:

```
const obj1 = kv("a", 123);
// const obj1: {a: number}
const obj2 = kv(Math.random() < 0.5 ? "a" : "b", 123);
// const obj2: {a: number} | {b: number}
```

Okay, looks good.  Now we can use this helper in your method:

```
  public async appendPresignedUrl<T, K extends PropertyKey>(
    value: T,
    targetProperty: K,
  ) {
    const presignedUrl = "abc"

    return {
      ...value,
      ...kv(targetProperty, presignedUrl),
    };
  }
```

The type of that method is

```
/* (method) Foo.appendPresignedUrl<T, K extends PropertyKey>(
    value: T, targetProperty: K): Promise<T & { 
      [P in K]: { [Q in P]: string; }; }[K]> */
```

Note that I didn't add an extra [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter `R` there; it would be superfluous to do so, and then the compiler would be rightly concerned that maybe `R` isn't the type you think it is, since callers choose generic type parameters and not implementers.  Instead of `R` you just need that `T & {[P in K]: {[Q in P]: string}}[K]` type directly.

Let's test that it works as desired:

```
const f = new Foo().appendPresignedUrl({ a: 123 }, "hello");
/* const f: Promise<{ a: number; } & { hello: string; }> */

const g = new Foo().appendPresignedUrl({ a: 123 }, 
  Math.random() < 0.5 ? "hello" : "goodbye");
/* const g: Promise<{ a: number; } & (
    { hello: string; } | { goodbye: string; })> */
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAawG4B4DSiCmAPKHMAEwGdEAFAJzgAccqoBPTHJgGkQDUA+ACmRsAXIkydUAQwA2IHCK4BKRAG8AsAChEiKjiggqSZYgDagpgF0RkmTkQBfRBPJHjFRDCSZLKkwEV3SBTeXPb2xl4A3Bp2GhoQCKRQiHAARgBWAIyIALwoqHwARBIFnBkATADMClHqAPS1iPFgicnpGSLKEiJgIAC2KQwx6k0tqWllOXl8ALISUAAWAHRUEiRwvXxK6IgADIsArIgA-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-c5LmJWFiBSJgcC-B4413YkgJobte3QMDPmBBgoKHMjYI-BCoDnMAF1Cf4jF4lMBLkRBEM05cFBQrd1A0IA)

Comment: I really appreciate the effort you put into this answer!
Although this works I'm not certain that we want to include this in our codebase. `kv` is extremely cryptic to read and defining proper/readable return types is close to impossible...

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't want `R` since that means someone could pass the wrong type to it explicitly:

```
appendPresignedUrl<{ foo: "" }, "bar", never>(...); // clearly wrong, because this shouldn't return `never`.
```

That's why TypeSccript is warning you about this.

Instead, you get rid of `R` entirely:

```
appendPresignedUrl<T, K extends PropertyKey>(
    value: T,
    fileProperty: keyof T,
    targetProperty: K,
): Promise<T & Record<K, string>>
```

`K` is also supposed to be any key, instead of `keyof R`.
However, you will notice that we get an error when we try to return now, and that is because TypeScript for whatever reason makes it type `{ [x: string]: string }`.

I don't know any way around it, so the simplest method I have found is just using an assertion with `as`.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mqk7Qw)